# SQL Server Get URL Beginning TSQL Only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

Without requiring SQLCLR to use a Regex in C#, what is the best way to get just the "stem" of a URL from a table with 500 million rows? The column is VarChar(3000) and the table has rows like this:

```
http://a.com
http://b.au
http://c.edu?a=3
http://d.com/?a=3
http://d.com/?a=3&b=2
http://d.com/?a=3&b=2
```

I need to select from the table and get this result set:

```
http://a.com             1 
http://b.au              1
http://c.edu             1       
http://d.com             3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about;

```
;with test (url) as (
    select 'http://a.com' union
    select 'http://b.au' union
    select 'http://c.edu?a=3' union
    select 'http://d.com/?a=3' union
    select 'http://d.com/?a=3&b=2' union all
    select 'http://d.com/?a=3&b=2'
)
select
    rtrim(replace(left(url, charindex('?', url + '?', 1) - 1) + ' ', '/ ', ''))
from test


>>>
http://a.com
http://b.au
http://c.edu
http://d.com
http://d.com
```

Change to

```
...,COUNT(*)
from test
    group by rtrim(replace(left(url, charindex('?', url + '?', 1) - 1) + ' ', '/ ', ''))
```

for the group.

Comment: If you wish to do this in pure T-SQL then this is the way to go.  However depending on your desired endstate you may be better of doing the string formatting in your application or presentation layers.  String formatting is simply not one of SQL's strengths.

Answer (score 3):

If all your URL "stems" all end with '?' or '/?', you can use this.  Additional cutoff patterns can be added into the CASE statements as required:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (URL varchar(3000))

INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://a.com')
INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://b.au')
INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://c.edu?a=3')
INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://d.com/?a=3')
INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://d.com/?a=3&b=2')
INSERT INTO @test (URL) VALUES ('http://d.com/?a=3&b=2')

SELECT SUBSTRING(URL, 0, 
    CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%/?%', URL) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%/?%', URL)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%?%', URL) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%?%', URL)
        ELSE LEN(URL) + 1
    END), COUNT(*)
FROM @test
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(URL, 0, 
    CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%/?%', URL) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%/?%', URL)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%?%', URL) > 0 THEN PATINDEX('%?%', URL)
        ELSE LEN(URL) + 1
    END)
```